# how to create new a belongs_to associate model in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise, associations

I have an 2 models, landlord and properties, property belongs to a singular landlord, landlord has many properties.

I want to build a new property when I log in as landlord, but currently it is throwing `NoMethodError (undefined method 'landlords_id' for #<Property:0x007fa74060a420>)`

I don't have `landlords_id` anywhere in my code, I am tearing my hair out.

Here is my landlords model

```
class Landlord < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :properties

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:authentication_keys => [:username]   
end
```

this is my property model

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :landlord
end
```

this is my `properties_controller.rb`

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_landlord!
  layout 'dash'

  def create
    @property = current_landlord.properties.build(property_params)
    @landlord = current_landlord

    if @property.save    

      redirect_to :controller=>'invites', :action => 'new' ,:landlord_id => @landlord.slug, :property_id => @property.slug

    else
      flash.now[:error] ="Failed To Add Property, Please Check Your Input"
      render 'new'
    end

  end
```

end

the error specifically points to line 28, which is `if @property.save`

which makes me believe that
 `@property = current_landlord.properties.build(property_params)`

is running into `undefined method`landlords_id' for #`

but I don't even know where that is coming from.

what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Some place in your code you are using `landlords_id` instead of `landlord_id` (singular). First place to search: `views/properties/new.*` and `views/properties/_form.*`.